# Website should open only if we install certificate

Tags: security, https, web

Is there a way, where we can restrict website to open if we don't install a certificate.

I tried googling, am not getting an hint on how i can do that.

Can someone suggest.

Example - If i install a particular certificate on my PC/Lap then the website should be accessible by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the website with two way SSL/TLS so the client (your browser) has to provide a certificate to be able to connect as well as the server (which normally provides a cert anyway).

Setting it up depends on your web browser and web server but Google "HTTPS client certificate Apache Chrome" or equivalent and you'll find lots of info.